# how can i get my shading for an image texture back?

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a game and my floor when I was done with the texture is not affected by any shade or light. what am I doing wrong? I set up my image texture like this [image: my node setup] what should i add or take away?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't make your questions a guessing game. Describe in detail what you are doing and how and add screenshots all relevant information so we can help you. As it stands this question is not answerable.

Comment: ok ill edit with a bit more detail.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help others understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: ok i added a photo and some details